# Node.js: Why do I get 'cannot post /upload' when using post routes in my project with multiple forms?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, multer

My project consists of multiple form with post method that inserts data into database
The issue is all the post route doesn't work (It displays cannot post /upload) expecet one i.e /publicationaction but as soon as i submit succesfully data thorugh /publicationaction other also start working.It always happen after the server is started or restarted.

`This is ejs code of /publicationaction`

```
<form  action="/publicationaction" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <table id="table-mix">
        <tr>
          <td>Paper Title*</td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Paper Title" name="Papertitle"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Year of Publication*</td>
          <td><input type="number" min="1970" required max="2099" class="form-control" placeholder="Year of Publication" name="Yearofpublication"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>URL/DOI</td>
          <td><input type="url" class="form-control" placeholder="URL/DOI" name="urldoi"></td>
        </tr>
    
        <tr>
          <td>
            <label> Publication Type </label>  </td>
         <td> <select class="form-control" id="dropdownlist2" required placeholder="Publication Type" name="Publicationtype" onChange=showHide2()  >  
          <option value = "default" selected disabled> ------------SELECT----------------
          </option> 
           <option value = "Journal"> Journal   
           </option>  
        <option value = "Conference"> Conference   
          </option>  
       <option value = "Book"> Book  
           </option>  
         <option value = "Book Chapter"> Book Chapter  
             </option>  
          </select>  
          </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="tr_jhide" required  hidden>
            <td>Journal Name</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="journalname" placeholder="Journal Name" name="journalname" disabled></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>ISSN NO.</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ISSN NO" name="issno" required></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
          <td>
            <label for="Index"> Index </label>  </td>
         <td> <select class="form-control" id="dropdownlist1" placeholder="Index" name="Index" onChange=showHide() >  
          <option value = "default" selected disabled> ------------SELECT----------------
          </option>  
          <option value = "UGC care list"> UGC care list   
           </option>  
        <option value = "Peer reviewed" > Peer reviewed   
          </option>  
       <option value="Scopus"> Scopus  
           </option>  
         <option value="Web of Science"> Web of Science 
             </option>  
          </select>  
          </td>
        
        </tr>  
         
        
        <tr id="tr_hide0" hidden>
          <td>Google scholar id</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="Googlescholarid" class="form-control" placeholder="Google scholar id" name="Googlescholarid" required disabled></td>
        </tr>  
      
        
        <tr id="tr_hide1" hidden>
          <td>Scopus id</td>
          <td><input type="text"  id="scopusid" class="form-control" placeholder="Scopus id" name="Scopusid" disabled required></td>
        </tr>
          
      
        <tr id="tr_hide2" hidden>
          <td>Web of Science id</td>
          <td><input type="text" id="WebofScienceid" class="form-control" placeholder="Web of Science id" name="WebofScienceid" hidden >
          <p>
            <input type="radio" id="SCI" name="WebofScience" value="SCI" disabled required>
            <label for="SCI">SCI</label>
            <input type="radio" id="SCIE" name="WebofScience" value="SCIE" disabled required>
            <label for="SCIE">SCIE</label>
            <input type="radio" id="SSCI" name="WebofScience" value="SSCI" disabled required>
            <label for="SSCI">SSCI</label>
          </p>
        <p>
                    <input type="radio" id="Q1" name="Quartile" value="Q1" disabled required>
                    <label for="Q1">Q1</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="Q2" name="Quartile" value="Q2" disabled required>
                    <label for="Q2">Q2</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="Q3" name="Quartile" value="Q3" disabled required>
                    <label for="Q3">Q3</label>
                    <input type="radio" id="Q4" name="Quartile" value="Q4" disabled required>
                    <label for="Q4">Q4</label>
        </p></td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
      <td colspan="2"> <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="True"/>
        <label for="checkbox">I have updated the college MIS and other profiles  </label></td> 
      </tr>
      </table>
      <br>
      
          <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle" align="center"><span>Submit </span></button>
    
      </form>
```

`This is the /publicationaction express route in app.js`

```
app.post('/publicationaction',upload.single('upload_proof'),function(req, res) {
   
        
    
    var Facultyid = facultyid;
    
     var Papertitle =req.body.Papertitle;
     var Yearofpublication =req.body.Yearofpublication;
     var urldoi =req.body.urldoi;
     var Publicationtype =req.body.Publicationtype;
     var Index =req.body.Index;
     var Googlescholarid =req.body.Googlescholarid;
     var Scopusid =req.body.Scopusid;
     var journalname =req.body.journalname;
     var issno =req.body.issno;
     var checkbox =req.body.checkbox;
     if(!(req.body.WebofScience)==0 && !(req.body.Quartile)==0)
     {
     var webofscience =req.body.WebofScience;
     var quartile =req.body.Quartile;
     }
     else{
        var webofscience ="";
        var quartile ="";
     }
     
    
     
     
     if(checkbox=='True')
     {
    
        dbconnection.getConnection(function(err,connection)
     {
      if (err) throw err;
      var sql ="Insert into publication (facultyid,Paper_Title,Year_of_publiucation,URL_DOI,Publication_type,Indexx,Google_scholar_id,Scopus_id,activitytime,action,webofscience,journalname,issn_no) VALUES ? ";
      var sql2="Insert into log_data (activity,dateandtime) VALUES ('"+Facultyid+" "+" submitted publication "+"','"+formatted+"')";
      var values=[
       [Facultyid,Papertitle,Yearofpublication,urldoi,Publicationtype,Index,Googlescholarid,Scopusid,formatted,defaultaction,webofscience+'-'+quartile,journalname,issno]
      ]
      
      connection.query(sql,[values],function(err, result){
       if (err) {
        throw err;
        }
       else{
       connection.query(sql2,function(err,result){
        if (err) {throw err;}
        else{
           req.flash('message','Submitted Successfully');
           
           res.redirect('/Publication');
        }

       });
       
       
       }
       
       
       
      });
      connection.release();
     }) ;
     
    }
    else{
        req.flash('message','Please Update the MIS');
        
        res.redirect('/Publication');
    }
```

`This is copyright .ejs`

```
 <form  action="/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> *
                <table id="table-mix">
                    <tr>
                      <td> Title*</td>
                      <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" name="title" required></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>URL(if any)</td>
                       
                        <td><input type="url" class="form-control" placeholder="Url" name="url"></td>
                        
                    </tr>
                    
                   <tr>
                   <td> date</td>
                   <td><input type="date" class="form-control" placeholder="date" name="date" required></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                    <td>Status*</td>
                    <td><input type="radio" id="Submitted" name="Status" value="Submitted">
                        <label for="Submitted">Submitted</label>
                        <input type="radio" id="Published" name="Status" value="Published">
                        <label for="Published">Published</label>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td> <label for="Online">Upload proof</label></td>
                    <td><input type="file" id="upload_proof" name="upload_proof" accept=".jpg,.pdf"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2"> <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="True"/>
                      <label for="checkbox">I have updated the college MIS and other profiles  </label></td> 
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br>
               
                <button class="button" style="vertical-align:middle" align="center"><span>Submit </span></button>
                </div>
                
            </form>
```

`This is /upload route in app.js`

```
app.post('/upload',upload.single('upload_proof'),function(req, res) 
{
    
    var Facultyid = facultyid;
    // var Facultyname =req.body.Facultyname;
     var title =req.body.title;
     var Url =req.body.url;
     var date =req.body.date;
     var Status =req.body.Status;
     try{if(!req.file.path == 0)     {
        var path = req.file.path;
        }
         }
         catch(e){
           var path = "No Data";
         }
     var checkbox =req.body.checkbox;
     
     if(checkbox=='True')
     {
    
        dbconnection.getConnection(function(err,connection)
     {
      if (err) throw err;
      var sql ="Insert into copyrights (facultyid,Title,Url,date,status,path,activitytime,action) VALUES ? ;";
   
      var values=[
       [Facultyid,title,Url,date,Status,path,formatted,defaultaction]
      ]
   
      connection.query(sql,[values],function(err, result)
      {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
            }
           else{
           req.flash('message','Submitted Successfully');
           
           res.redirect('/Copyrights');
           }
       
      });
      connection.release();
     }) ;
     
     }
     else{
        req.flash('message','Please Update the MIS');
        
        res.redirect('/Copyrights');
    }

     
   
});
```

I am confused. I tried change some code but i am stuck